# Printf functions when referring to strings

Tags: c, printf

If

```
char d[3];
     d[0] ='p';
     d[1] ='o';
     d[2] ='\0';
```

how come

```
printf("%s\n",d[0]);
```

won't work properly.

But if I have

```
char n[2][4];
n[0][0]=’T’; n[0][1]=’o’; n[0][2]=’m’; n[0][3]=0;
n[1][0]=’S’; n[1][1]=’u’; n[1][2]=’e’; n[1][3]=0;
```

`printf("%s %s\n", n[0],n[1]);`

it will print the entire string?

Comment: d[0] is only a character while n[0],n[1] is an array of characters which is also called as string

Comment: To build on the other comments, n[0] works, but n[0][0] would fail just as d[0] does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try and print yor string `d`, you pass it the first character of the array:

```
printf("%s\n",d[0]);
```

1. `d[0]` means "The thing stored in index `0` of array `d`". This is the literal character `'p'` and not the beginning of the string.
2. Passing a character to `printf` with the string (`%s`) us undefined behaviour and could cause problems. Don't do it

When printing a string with `printf` you need to pass a pointer to the string, which is the pointer to the first element of the string (and not the element itself).

```
&d[0];
^^ ^
|| Index 0
|array d
Address of
```

This evaluates to the address of the `0`th index of array `d`.
Additionally, we can take advantage of the fact that arrays degrade to pointers of the type.

```
&d[0] == &(*(d+0)) == d
```

This means that we can do away with the `&` and `[]` operators and just pass in `d`:

```
printf("%s\n", d);
```

This will print the string.

With your second example, having the two dimensional array `[][]` provides an extra level of indirection (equates to a `char **`).
This means that when you were calling `printf`, when you were passing in `n[0]` and `n[1]`, you were actually passing in the pointer to the first character in each string. i.e. `&n[0][0]` and `&n[1][0]`.

<kbd>[ideone example](http://ideone.com/MpYwzK)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
 d[0] - is a character
```

And

```
 n - is and array of and array of characters. I.e. an array of strings
```

Answer (score 2):

`d[0]` is the first *character* contained in the array whereas `printf` requires the *address* of that first character.

It's that address that you get when you use `d` in your source code, or you can explicitly work it out with `&(d[0])`, the address of the character that's at the address at the start of the array :-).

The reason why your two-dimensional arrays work is exactly the same: `n[0]` is the *address* of `n[0][0]`, the same way that `d` is the address of `d[0]`.

If you were to pass `n[0][0]` (the character) to `printf`, you would have the same problem as when you passed `d[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s\n",d[0]);` is technically [`undefined behavior`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The documentation for [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) describes the various conversion specifiers.

> **s**
>
> If no l modifier is present: The const char * argument is expected to
>   be a pointer to an array of character type (pointer to a string).
>   Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) a
>   terminating null byte ('\0');

If you enable warnings, i.e. `-Wall`, you may get:

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 
         'int' [-Wformat=]
      printf("%s\n",d[0]);
```

For why the second example works, read about [array-to-pointer conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying). James McNellis writes:

> In both C and C++, an array can be used as if it were a pointer to its
>   first element. Effectively, given an array named x, you can replace
>   most uses of `&x[0]` with just x.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> void f(int* p);
>
> int x[5];
> f(x);     // this is the same as f(&x[0])
> ```

So `n[0]` is equivalent to `&n[0][0]`, just as `d` is equivalent to `&d[0]`. But `d` is *not* equivalent to `d[0]`.